# chdir gives different outputs using function in a WINDOWS environment

Tags: c, windows, gcc, chdir

I want to program a function which easy check if the path variable is correct or if it includes a missing path.

That is what I got:

C:>CheckPath

PATH[ 0]="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"                     ok
PATH[ 1]="C:\WINDOWS\system32"                                                          ok
PATH[ 2]="C:\WINDOWS"                                                                   ok
PATH[ 3]="C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"                                   ok
**PATH[ 4]="C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH"                                           does not exist**
chdir error:: No such file or directory
PATH[ 5]="C:\Program Files (x86)\IncrediBuild"                                          ok
PATH[ 6]="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared"                                   ok

The question is why C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH gives an error cd C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH shows that it is possible to reach the folder.

The code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* sprintf */  
#include <unistd.h>  /* chdir */  
#include <stdlib.h>  /*getenv */  
#include <limits.h>  
#include <string.h>  

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
   char *path,*pstr,Folder[500],Folder1[502];  
   char *var = "path";  
   int i,out,k,error;  

   if( (path = getenv(var)) == NULL)  
      {  
         printf("%s is not a environmental variable", var);  
         printf(" Check: Systemsteuerung-> System->Erweitert->Umgebungsvariablen->PATH\n");  
      }

   pstr=path;  
   i=0;  
   out=FALSE;  
   k=0;  

   do{  
      while(*pstr != ';' && *pstr != '\0'){  
         Folder[i]=*pstr;  
         pstr++;  
         i++;  
      }  

      /* remove from  C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\   '\' Otherwise maybe it will not work */  

      while( (i>0) && (Folder[i-1] == '\\') ){  
         i--;  
      }  
      while( (i>0) && (Folder[i-1] == ' ')  ){  
         i--;  
      }  

      Folder[i]='\0';  
      i=0;  

      if(*pstr == '\0')  
         out=TRUE;  
      else{  
         pstr++;  
         if(*pstr == '\0')  
            out=TRUE;  
      }  
      /* Check String Folder */  

     error = chdir(Folder);  
     sprintf(Folder1,"\"%s\"",Folder);  
     if(error == -1){  
        printf("PATH[%2d]=%-50s\t\t\t\tdoes not exist\n",k,Folder1);  
        perror("chdir error:");  
     }else{  
        printf("PATH[%2d]=%-50s\t\t\t\tok\n",k,Folder1);  
     }  

     k++;  
   }while(out==FALSE);  
   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Check `errno` to get more information about the error. See man page `chdir(2)`.

Comment: Maybe 32bit vs 64bit issue.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  Neither of the parameters `argc` nor `argv[]` are used in the posted code.  This results in the compiler outputting two warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest either 1) using the other valid signature for main() `int main( void )`  or using the (more obscure ) `int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {  (void)argc; (void)argv);`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *path,*pstr,Folder[500],Folder1[502];  
   char *var = "path";  
   int i,out,k,error; `  Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: regarding: `printf("PATH[%2d]=%-50s\t\t\t\tdoes not exist\n",k,Folder1);  
        perror("chdir error:");`  these two statement should be in reversed as `printf()` also sets the `errno` variable

Comment: regarding: `while(*pstr != ';' && *pstr != '\0')
      {  
         Folder[i]=*pstr;  
         pstr++;  
         i++;  
      } `  This is not reliable.  Suggest using `strtok()` to break down the $PATH$ string into its' separate components.

Comment: regarding: `while( (i>0) && (Folder[i-1] == ' ')  ){  
         i--;  
      } `  This will not work for folders like: `program files`

Comment: errno=ENOENT = 2  /* No such file or directory */

Comment: Maybe 32bit vs 64bit issue:  must be considered further:                                  x86_64-w64-mingw32: 64-bit Windows
i686-w64-mingw32: 32-bit Windows

gcc -v Target: i686-w64-mingw32  but I use a windows 10 64 bit system  so I have to change the compiler

Comment: Thanks to all for the valuable inputs, problem is solved. I change the gcc compiler  gcc -v shows now Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32  for Windows 10 and it is working